# Cannot find Data Extension by external key.

Tags: marketing-cloud, http, post

I am getting the response from 
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/BBDD0F10-94A1-4CD6-B7A2-32FEB671E44F/rowset

```
{
    "message": "Unable to locate data extension with ID bbdd0f10-94a1-4cd6-b7a2-32feb671e44f",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

here is my request object.

```
[
    {
        "keys": {
            "MKTG_ID": "1"
        },
        "values": {
            "Email_Address": "jimmy@example.com",
            "First_Name": "John",
            "Last_Name": "Doe",
            "Preferred_Name": "John Smith",
            "Account_State": "VA",
            "Account_State_Last_Changed": "PN",
            "Archived": 0
        }
    }
]
```

It says a data extension with this id does not exist when this is the external key. Documentation says I have to pass the customer key. Are the external key and the customer key the same thing? Where do I find the customer key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the customer key in this case refers to the external key that's specified when you create the extension as shown below. [image]

Answer (score 9):

The issue lies with the autogenerated GUID for the External/Customer Key (those names are interchangeable) and the Object ID GUID, which is not visible in the UI.

For your particular call, if you are grabbing `BBDD0F10-94A1-4CD6-B7A2-32FEB671E44F` from the UI, then your API call should be

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:BBDD0F10-94A1-4CD6-B7A2-32FEB671E44F/rowset
```

Comment: adding the `key:` to the url worked for me. weird that the docs suggest leaving this out would work.

Comment: this is the correct answer

Comment: The current Documentation is inconsistent in on example it says: `/key:SomeKey/` and in the other it just adds the key like `/11954DDF-28A3-4FE8-BF77-646C37506621/`